# OpenCV displays the image triplicated in a single frame

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to build an application to simply get, save and show some frames from my camera, a DMK 41BU02 (you can consult the specifications of the device in the following link: [datasheet](http://s1.archive.theimagingsource.com/publications/factsheets-single/fsdmk41bu02/35d304da84690031e6f8503c931a9c37e560eff469d5ea58c435f5cae2c89558/fsdmk41bu02.en_US.pdf))

My code is as simple as that:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char**)
{
    String path="~/proof.jpg";
    VideoCapture cap(1); // /dev/video0 is the integrated webcam of my laptop, while /dev/video1 is the DMK41BU02 camera
    cvNamedWindow( "Video", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    imwrite(path, frame);
    imshow("Video", frame);
    waitkey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles and executes whithout any problem, but the error arrives when the image is shown on the window or saved in the jpg file, because I get something like the following jpg, where the image is **triplicated** in the frame:

[Resulting image of the code shown above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0ZnV.jpg)

Some aspects to remark:

1. The code executes normally and returns normal images when working
   with the integrated webcam of my laptop.
2. The DMK41BU02 camera works normally and returns normal images when working with another application, such as fswebcam or VLC.
3. The camera datasheet says it is compatible with OpenCV.
4. I have also tried the code with an infinite loop, as I know the first frame grabbed can be blank or with some type of error, but the problem is still there.
5. I have had some issues installing the camera drivers, but I think they're all resolved.
6. The laptop is a 32-bit machine with Ubuntu installed on it. Here you can see the output of `uname -a`: `Linux AsusPC 3.11.0-18-generic #32~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 20 17:54:21 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

I have no idea of how to debug this problem and, of course, I don't know where the error could be. Could you give me any hint, please?

Thank you very much.

---

---

**UPDATE:** I forgot to post the weird outputs that the application writes in the terminal at the very beginning of the program:

```
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
libv4l2: error set_fmt gave us a different result then try_fmt!
HIGHGUI ERROR: libv4l unable convert to requested pixfmt
libv4l2: error set_fmt gave us a different result then try_fmt!
init done 
opengl support available
```

Comment: waitkey(0) seems to wait 0ms to paint image and seems to be mispelled (code compiles?), use waitKey(10); Also can you cout frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.ch, frame.type()?

Comment: @Vlad doesn't `waitKey(0)` wait until a key is pressed? I always use `waitKey(-1)` for that, so I'm not sure =)
@Alejandro I guess that openCV misinterprets the image data of your camera (looks like all 3 color channels are within a much too big grayscale image), but I don't have much experience with the `VideoCapture` objects, so I can't tell you how to fix that.

Comment: As far as I know, waitKey(0) waits forever until a key is pressed, and so is what my program do.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not post my whole comment, here is the rest:

I let you here, @Vlad, the cout you requested (except frame.ch, as I don't know what do you mean by it):
COLS: 1280
ROWS: 960
TYPE: 16

Comment: Well, I meant m.channels(), sorry. 16 means that your image type is CV_8UC3 which is 3 channels rgb unsigned char array as required. So there should be some problem in the camera or opecCV code, not your code. The three images aren't exact replicas though (pay attention to 4 bright clusters of dots in the lower right corner) so I would check your camera first. A for yuv formats - uv is usually compressed 4 times compared to Y but your images are the same size so this is not the case.

Comment: Ok, @Vlad, the frame.channels() returns `3` so there might be some error regarding the number of channels (because my camera is monochrome), isn't it? In the answer of @Nalltah he said there's some problem with the OpenCV code, but I do not know how to solve it. Any ideas? And, how do I check/debug my camera?
Thank you very much.
P.S:I don'tsee those 4 bright clusters of dots, you have a super-vision!!!

Comment: You HAD to say that your camera is monochrome on the first place! You just read 3 frames with cap>>frame command, that’s all. See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same problem. The issue is within openCV itself, or more so; how  cap_v4l.hpp (in the highgui module) and cap_libv4l.hpp are implemented.

The issue here is that OpenCV appearantly uses a wrong video type or channel type to read the data. Try playing arround with the different types (yuyv variants, etc) inside the opencv lib.

For some magical reason the cap_v4l.hpp is the code thats actually used by opencv and the code in cap_lib4l is not used, but seems to support more vide formats (It could be switched arround, i'm not sure about that).

Switching these files and recompiling opencv did improve stuff for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Nallta, but I'm not sure if I understood you; I have been looking for those files and I only found a cap_v4l.cpp in my machine, in which there are some references to these YUYV variants, but I don't know what to do with them. Could you be a little bit more explicit? Thank you very much for your time.
Take also a look at the updated question, so I posted the output that is written in the terminal at the very beginning of the program.
Thank you again!:)

Comment: I do have a cap_lib4vl.cpp, it was part of the 2.4.8 release of opencv. The extra errors you posted are the same I've had. Switching the code solved those problems for me.

Comment: Thank you again, @Nallath! But what do you mean by switching the code? Copyying the content of cap_lib4l into the other one?

Comment: Thats what I did. You do need to recompile it afterwards though.

Comment: I tried yesterday to recompile OpenCV after have switched the code of cap_libv4l.cpp and cap_v4l.cpp (I don't have a .hpp nor a .h)
However,my program doesn't compile anymore now, it says that `cvNamedWindow` and `CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` are "not declared in this scope". I tried to wrote cv::cvNamedWindow but it doesn't work.
Any other idea? Why I don't have the .hpp files in my machine?
Thank you very much

Comment: THe .hpp files were my bad, it only has the .cpp files. 

I never use the cvNamedWindow, just the cv::imshow("windowname",imgMat).

Answer (score 0):

Since after the call to cap>>frame you have three channel (type=16), your capture is unaware that your camera is monochrome. Use [grab-retrieve pairs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=video%20capture#VideoCapture) instead since retrieve specifies number of channels.

```
bool VideoCapture::grab()  
bool VideoCapture::retrieve(Mat& image, int channel=0)
```

Here is example [code](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/openni_capture.cpp) that also shows how to set camera parameters. You can also try to set some camera parameters that explicitly declare monochrome mode. If everything else fails you can always cut one image out of your triple with

```
Rect rect(0, 0, frame.cols/3, frame.rows);
Mat true_img = frame(rect).clone();
```

However, I kind of like what happens in your case. You have a natural frame queue and can analyze motion an possibly structure by looking at what happens in three consecutive frames.

Comment: Thank you, that seems a pretty good solution!! I'll try it tomorrow and we'll see :)

Comment: The grab-retrieve solution did't work :(
Before deciding to simply crop the image, I will try other solutions, thank you!!